# How to wrap workflow foundation into API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, workflow-foundation

I am looking for some simple and modern approach of hosting workflows in WCF or ASP.NET. Just some layer to receive data from outside and put it into workflow - or get and return data from some workflow on demand. The examples I've seen are so old they aren't even running on VS 2017.

Answer (score 0):

Use App Fabric to instant deploy WF as a service.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677312%28v=azure.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396